# Sum of even integers from a to b in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
def sum_even(a, b):
    count = 0
    for i in range(a, b, 1):
        if(i % 2 == 0):
            count += [i]
        return count
```

An example I put was print(sum_even(3,7)) and the output is 0. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `sum(i for i in range(a, b) if i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: Look into arithmetic progression.

Comment: Which `if` statement is the `return` associated with? Spacing is significant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your indentation is off, it should be:

```
def sum_even(a, b):
    count = 0
    for i in range(a, b, 1):
        if(i % 2 == 0):
            count += i
    return count
```

so that `return count` doesn't get scoped to your for loop (in which case it would return on the 1st iteration, causing it to return 0)

(And change `[i]` to `i`)

---

**NOTE:** another problem - you should be careful about using `range`:

```
>>> range(3,7)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

so if you were to do calls to:

- `sum_even(3,7)`
- `sum_even(3,8)`

right now, they would both output `10`, which is incorrect for sum of even integers between 3 and 8, inclusive.

What you really want is probably this instead:

```
def sum_even(a, b):
    return sum(i for i in range(a, b + 1) if i % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: I tested print(sumEven(3,7)) and the output was 0

Comment: @knd15 did you mean to test it with `print sum_even(3,7)` instead?

Comment: @knd15 I noted another problem in the answer about `range`, make sure you see the edit =)

Comment: So if you are going to advise on using `range()`, why not use `range(a + (a % 2) b + 1, 2)`? `a + (a % 2)` gets you `a` if `a + 0` is even, otherwise it gets you `a + 1`. You can also use `a + 1 if a % 2 else a`.

Answer (score 5):

1. Move the `return` statement out of the scope of the `for` loop (otherwise you will return on the first loop iteration).
2. Change `count += [i]` to `count += i`.

---

Also (not sure if you knew this), `range(a, b, 1)` will contain all the numbers from `a` to `b - 1` (not `b`). Moreover, you don't need the `1` argument: `range(a,b)` will have the same effect. So to contain all the numbers from `a` to `b` you should use `range(a, b+1)`.

Probably the quickest way to add all the even numbers from `a` to `b` is

```
sum(i for i in xrange(a, b + 1) if not i % 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make it far simpler than that, by properly using the step argument to the range function.

```
def sum_even(a, b):
    return sum(range(a + a%2, b + 1, 2))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the loop; you can use simple algebra:

```
def sum_even(a, b):
    if (a % 2 == 1):
        a += 1
    if (b % 2 == 1):
        b -= 1
    return a * (0.5 - 0.25 * a) + b * (0.25 * b + 0.5)
```

**Edit:**

As NPE pointed out, my original solution above uses floating-point maths. I wasn't too concerned, since the overhead of floating-point maths is negligible compared with the removal of the looping (e.g. if calling `sum_even(10, 10000)`). Furthermore, the calculations use (negative) powers of two, so shouldn't be subject by rounding errors.

Anyhow, with the simple trick of multiplying everything by 4 and then dividing again at the end we can use integers throughout, which is preferable.

```
def sum_even(a, b):
    if (a % 2 == 1):
        a += 1
    if (b % 2 == 1):
        b -= 1
    return (a * (2 - a) + b * (2 + b)) // 4
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if it didn't use floating-point maths to compute an integer sum.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like you see how your loops work if b is close to 2^32 ;-)
As Matthew said there is no loop needed but he does not explain why.

The problem is just simple arithmetic sequence [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). Sum of all items in such sequence is:

```
      (a+b)  
Sn = ------- * n  
        2
```

where 'a' is a first item, 'b' is last and 'n' is number if items. 
If we make 'a' and b' even numbers we can easily solve given problem.
So making 'a' and 'b' even is just:

```
if ((a & 1)==1):
    a = a + 1
if ((b & 1)==1):
    b = b - 1
```

Now think how many items do we have between two even numbers - it is:

```
    b-a
n = --- + 1
     2
```

Put it into equation and you get:

```
      a+b       b-a 
Sn = ----- * ( ------ + 1)
       2         2
```

so your code looks like:

```
def sum_even(a,b):
    if ((a & 1)==1):
        a = a + 1
    if ((b & 1)==1):
        b = b - 1
    return ((a+b)/2) * (1+((b-a)/2))
```

Of course you may add some code to prevent a be equal or bigger than b etc.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation matters in Python. The code you write returns after the first item processed.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simple way of doing it using the range function.
the third number in range is a step number, i.e, 0, 2, 4, 6...100

```
sum = 0
for even_number in range(0,102,2):
    sum += even_number
print (sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_even(a,b):
    count = 0
    for i in range(a, b):
        if(i % 2 == 0):
            count += i
     return count
```

Two mistakes here :

- add i instead of [i]
- you return the value directly at the first iteration. Move the return count out of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The **sum** of all the **even** numbers between the **start** and **end** number (**inclusive**).

```
 def addEvenNumbers(start,end):
  total = 0
  if end%2==0:
    for x in range(start,end):
      if x%2==0:
        total+=x
    return total+end
  else:
    for x in range(start,end):
      if x%2==0:
        total+=x
    return total
print addEvenNumbers(4,12)
```

Answer (score 0):

little bit more fancy with advanced python feature.

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a + b
def evensum(a,b):
    a = reduce(sum,[x for x in range(a,b) if x %2 ==0])
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

SUM of even numbers including min and max numbers:

```
def sum_evens(minimum, maximum):
    sum=0
    for i in range(minimum, maximum+1):
        if i%2==0:
           sum = sum +i
           i= i+1
    return sum

print(sum_evens(2, 6))
```

OUTPUT is : 12

sum_evens(2, 6) -> 12 (2 + 4 + 6 = 12)

Answer (score 0):

List based approach,
Use `b+1` if you want to include last value.

```
def sum_even(a, b):
    even = [x for x in range (a, b) if x%2 ==0 ]
    return sum(even)
   
print(sum_even(3,6))
```

```
4

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -1):

This will add up all your even values between 1 and 10 and output the answer which is stored in the variable x

```
x = 0 
for i in range (1,10):
    if i %2 == 0:
        x = x+1
        print(x)
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting tools, either backticks or four spaces to delineate code, especially in Python where indentation matters.