# How can I find the sum of every even number in a certain range using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

I want to write a script that prints the sum of every even number between the range of [0, 100]. And so far, this is what I've got.

I've tried putting the results in a list so then I can take the sum of that list, but I keep getting the "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" message.

```
def sum_even_num(start, stop):
    
    for x in range(start, stop):
        if (x % 2 == 0):
            print(x)

sum_even_num(0, 100)
```

Comment: You have managed to write a loop that will print the numbers you're interested in. Now just make a starting variable set to zero before the loop, add each `x` to that instead of printing it, and return the result.

Comment: If you want to find out how to fix the code building the list, you'll have to post it.

Comment: rather that printing x, try adding it to something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of even integers from a to b in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809159/sum-of-even-integers-from-a-to-b-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a local variable to store the partial result.

```
def sum_even_num(start, stop):
    result = 0
    for x in range(start, stop):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            result += x
    return result

print(sum_even_num(0, 10))
```

Another way to do this would be to use the `sum` builtin function and a generator expression:

```
def sum_even_num(start, stop):
    return sum(x for x in range(start, stop) if x % 2 == 0)

print(sum_even_num(0, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works, and in constant time:

```
def sum_even_num(start,stop):
   a = (start+1)//2
   b = stop//2
   return (a+b) * (b-a+1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def sum_even_num(start,stop):
    res = 0
    for i in range(start,stop+1):
         if i%2==0:
             res+=i
    return res
```

Comment: Avoid using variable names which shadow python built-in functions/classes https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html